# Show folder in the tree view in Atom

Tags: atom-editor

When I am using rubymine, I can open a panel with ctrl+shift+n and enter something like "users/" and it will show me the users folder in the tree view on the left, how can I do the same in Atom editor? I can open files with ctrl + p, but I can't find anything about going to the folder.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It looks like this functionality is currently not available in Atom. Some related information:

- You can reveal the currently edited file in the Tree View using the menu entry `Packages > Tree View > Reveal Active File` or using the assigned keyboard shortcut (on OS X <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>)
- There's a [Tree View Filter package](https://atom.io/packages/tree-view-filter), which seems to be similar to what you're looking for.
- The [Tree View Search Bar package](https://atom.io/packages/tree-view-search-bar) allows to search the tree view's content.
- There's an [open issue](https://github.com/atom/tree-view/issues/159) on the Tree View package to add search capabilities, but it has not been implemented yet.

Comment: The issue on the original Tree View package is still open/unresolved.

Comment: Ok. Tree view filter only works on files, this plugin did what I wanted (show me folders than match search criteria) - https://atom.io/packages/tree-view-search-bar

Comment: Thanks - added it to the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Looks available to me?

> tree-view:reveal-active-file

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>|</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Try Shortcuts :   **`ctrl \` or `cmd \` to open/close the tree view**

if still not opening then check your `.atom/config.cson` 
and check `disabledPackages` and remove `tree-view` from it.
and restart your atom again.

if still not open then install it again

https://atom.io/packages/tree-view

NOTE : sometimes it happens if you uninstalled [Nuclide](https://atom.io/packages/nuclide) package

Comment: Thanks for this, I had uninstalled Nuclide and the tree-view package was disabled, re-enabled it and it is working now.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue after I installed the nuclide.

The problem was that the package disables the standard tree view.

Solution:

1. Go to Atom **Preference > Packages**
2. Enable core Package **tree-View**

Answer (score 1):

To do this select Atom > Preferences. When your settings show up, click on Packages in the left hand column. Search for the installed package, tree-view. Once it comes up, click on Settings and then uncheck the option Hide VCS Ignored Files.